# Calculator with one function

Tags: c

This calculator should work by using one function(switch/case).
Unfortunately i get compilation errors and I don`t understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2) {

switch(optr) {
case '+': ergebnis = opr1+opr2; break;
case '-': ergebnis = opr1-opr2; break;
case '*': ergebnis = opr1*opr2; break;
case '/': ergebnis = opr1/opr2; break;
case 'q': exit(0);
default: cout <<"unbekanntes Rechenzeichen...\n"; return1;
}
return ergebnis;
}


int main(void) {
char optr;
float opr1, opr2, ergebnis;

//Eingabe
printf("\nEingabe Operator(+,-,*,/,q)"); scanf("%c", &optr);
printf("\nEingabe Zahl1"); scanf("%f", &opr1);
printf("\nEingabe Zahl2"); scanf("%f", &opr2);

//Verarbeitung
ergebnis = calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2);//Ausgabe
printf("\nErgebnis: %f\n", ergebnis);
return 0;
}
```

What do I have to change?

```
prog.c: In function ‘calculate’:
prog.c:6:15: error: ‘ergebnis’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 case '+': ergebnis = opr1+opr2; break;
           ^
prog.c:6:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears   in
prog.c:10:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 case 'q': exit(0);
 ^
prog.c:10:15: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [-Werror]
 case 'q': exit(0);
           ^
prog.c:11:14: error: ‘cout’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 default: cout <<"unbekanntes Rechenzeichen...\n"; return1;
          ^
prog.c:11:55: error: ‘return1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 default: cout <<"unbekanntes Rechenzeichen...\n"; return1;
                                                   ^
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:27:26: error: expected expression before ‘char’
 ergebnis = calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2);//Ausgabe
                      ^
prog.c:27:26: error: too few arguments to function ‘calculate’
prog.c:3:11: note: declared here
 float calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2) {
       ^
prog.c: In function ‘calculate’:
prog.c:14:5: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

edit: sorry, forgot about the errors

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: The first thing you have to change is to add the errors messages to your question.

Comment: As you add the errors you get, try to understand them, and explain what exactly did you not understand in the error messages.

Comment: Note that `cout` does not work in C - it's a C++ thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. A few things you did wrong:

- `exit()` is in the library `stdlib.h`
- You have a return too much
- You forgot to declar `ergebnis`

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2) {
    float ergebnis;
    switch(optr) {
        case '+': ergebnis = opr1+opr2; break;
        case '-': ergebnis = opr1-opr2; break;
        case '*': ergebnis = opr1*opr2; break;
        case '/': ergebnis = opr1/opr2; break;
        case 'q': exit(0);
        default: printf("unbekanntes Rechenzeichen...\n");
    }
    return ergebnis;
}

int main(void) {
    char optr;
    float opr1, opr2, ergebnis;

    //Eingabe
    printf("\nEingabe Operator(+,-,*,/,q)"); scanf("%c", &optr);
    printf("\nEingabe Zahl1"); scanf("%f", &opr1);
    printf("\nEingabe Zahl2"); scanf("%f", &opr2);

    //Verarbeitung
    ergebnis = calculate(optr,  opr1,  opr2);//Ausgabe
    printf("\nErgebnis: %f\n", ergebnis);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also i would recommend you from german to german ;D To program with english words! (e.g. result, input, output and so on) So more people can understand your code and understand it faster!

Comment: Good answer - not sure why it got a down-vote but I'll happily give it an up-vote to cancel this out!

Comment: @PaulR Thanks! It honors me to hear something like this from you :D

Comment: @PaulR added a special hint in favor of OP!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ergebnis = calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2);
```

to

```
ergebnis = calculate(optr,opr1,opr2);
```

and add `float ergebnis;` in the `calculate` function.Also change `return1;` to `return 1;`.You also need to place some check to avoid division by zero. You've also used `cout` instead of `printf` in the `default` case.You need to include `<stdlib.h>` in order to use `exit(0);`

Answer (score 0):

- You need space between return and 1 as below:

  return 1;
- Need to call method without any type information of parameters like:

  ergebnis = calculate(optr,opr1,opr2);
- In your calculator function, you are using as a variable ergebnis but didnt defined it, so you should define it like below:

  float ergebnis = 0;
- You are using c, so remove cout and change it with printf.
- As per your error for exit function, you need to include stdlib.h like below

  #include

This should be the overall code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2) {
    float ergebnis = 0;
    switch(optr) {
    case '+': ergebnis = opr1+opr2; break;
    case '-': ergebnis = opr1-opr2; break;
    case '*': ergebnis = opr1*opr2; break;
    case '/': ergebnis = opr1/opr2; break;
    case 'q': exit(0);
    default: printf("unbekanntes Rechenzeichen...\n"); return 1;
}
return ergebnis;
}

int main(void) {
char optr;
float opr1, opr2, ergebnis;
//Eingabe
printf("\nEingabe Operator(+,-,*,/,q)"); scanf("%c", &optr);
printf("\nEingabe Zahl1"); scanf("%f", &opr1);
printf("\nEingabe Zahl2"); scanf("%f", &opr2);
//Verarbeitung
ergebnis = calculate(optr, opr1, opr2);//Ausgabe
printf("\nErgebnis: %f\n", ergebnis);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ergebnis = calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2);//Ausgabe

        float Calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2)
    {

        switch (optr)
        {
            case '+': return opr1 + opr2;
            case '-': return opr1 - opr2;
            case '*': return opr1 * opr2; 
            case '/': return opr1 / opr2;
            case 'q': return 0f;
            default: return 0f;
        }
    }
```

Your "Calculate function can only return a float"

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is about compilation errors please begin by providing an output of these errors.

It probably comes from this part of your code :

```
float calculate(char optr, float opr1, float opr2) {

switch(optr) {
case '+': ergebnis = opr1+opr2; break;
case '-': ergebnis = opr1-opr2; break;
case '*': ergebnis = opr1*opr2; break;
case '/': ergebnis = opr1/opr2; break;
case 'q': exit(0);
default: cout <<"unbekanntes Rechenzeichen...\n"; return1;
}
return ergebnis;
}
```

You didn't define the variable `ergebnis` before using or return it. Note that's not cause you get the return of this function into a variable called `ergebnis` from your `main()` function that you have to call it by the same name into the `calculate(...)` function.

Plus you don't need to specify parameters types when you call your `calculate()` function